# Display top border of table using csvreader

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I am using csvreader from the csvsimple package to generate a table in my document.  I am struggling to get a top border on the table. Here is the code, including writing the .csv

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists2.csv}
name,surname,
Albert,Einstein,
Marie,Curie,
Thomas,Edison
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|,
    table head=\textbf{ First Name} & \textbf{Last Nmae} \\\hline,
    late after line = \\\hline]%
{scientists2.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname}%
{\name & \surname}%

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

What argument can I pass (to tabular?) to see the top border?  I am using TexWorks to compile.  Thanks,

Comment: Happy to provide more feedback, but what is MWE?

Comment: @mike: MWE means [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. `csvsimple`:

You can simply adjust the `table head` to start with an `\hline`:

[image]

### 2. `booktabs`:

However, [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) is usually recommened to produce more *professional* looking tables. So, I have added a second example that uses this along with [the `datatool` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool):

[image]

Much thanks to Nicola Talbot, who helped with proper use of `booktabs` here.

### 3. `pgfplotstable`:

A solution using `pgfplotstable` is provided at [Bold one cell in table using CSV reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82249/bold-one-cell-in-table-using-csv-reader).

### Notes:

- Not sure why I needed the extra `\\` before the `\bottomrule` which is producing the additional spacing at the bottom. To fix this I added a manual `\vspace*{-12pt}`, which is more of a hack.
- It appears the the `csvsimple` package was discarding the last row as it did not have a trailing `,`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

% Make csv in question
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists2.csv}
name,surname,
Albert,Einstein,
Marie,Curie,
Thomas,Edison,
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \csvreader[tabular=|l|l|,
        table head=\hline \textbf{ First Name} & \textbf{Last Name} \\\hline,
        late after line = \\\hline]%
    {scientists2.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname}%
    {\name & \surname}%
\end{center}


\DTLloaddb{myDB}{scientists2.csv}
%\DTLdisplaydb{myDB}% Useful for debugging.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
    \textbf{First Name} & \textbf{Last Name}%
    \DTLforeach*{myDB}{\Name=name,\Surname=surname}{%
        \DTLiffirstrow{\\\cmidrule{1-2}}{\\}%
        \Name & \Surname
    }%
    \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, why does Thomas Edison not show up when this code is run?  Thanks for help with a new user!

Comment: Hmmm... Don't know as I have never used the `csvsimple` package, just really guessed at the solution (bad habit I picked up from David Carlisle :-)).  I was about to do a `datatool` solution for you using `booktabs` as I know that will work, and you can get a "better" table. As the missing data seems unrelated to displaying a top border, I would recommend you should post a separate question.

Comment: @mike: Found issue with last entry: Need a trailing `,` for some reason. See updated answer.