# Bold one cell in table using CSV reader

Tags: tables, formatting, bold, csvsimple

Is it possible to bold a single desired cell (or number of cells) using csvreader (besides the head)?  Here is an example of making the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists2.csv}
name,surname,
Albert,Einstein,
Marie,Curie,
Thomas,Edison
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|,
    table head=\hline \textbf{ First Name} & \textbf{Last Nmae} \\\hline,
    late after line = \\\hline]%
{scientists2.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname}%
{\name & \surname}%

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

I tried to use a filter to apply different rules, but was unsuccessful.  Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a direct answer but I would recommend the [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) for such tasks. It's quite comprehensive and file operations are quite convenient. It might seem like an overkill for this specific question but as the tasks get more complicated it reveals its true potential.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents,booktabs}

% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists2.csv}
name,surname
Albert,Einstein
Marie,Curie
Thomas,Edison
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{scientists2.csv}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
string type,
columns/name/.style={column name=Name},
columns/surname/.style={column name=Surname},
% Row/column numbering starts from zero
every row 1 column 1/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\textbf{##1}}},
every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row={\toprule}},
]\mytable
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for including such a detailed response -- really helps when just starting out!

Comment: @mike My pleasure.

Comment: Could you include how to align the contents of the cell in this framework (ie, conolum type = {|l}).  Thanks,

Comment: @mike Initially it's `c` for all columns but you can change it via `column type=|l|` etc. for the corresponding column. Have a look at the manual, bottom of page 10.

Comment: I'm unsuccessful when I put it inside the description: every head row/.style={column type={|l}, before row={\toprule},after row=\midrule},

Comment: @mike It goes into the separate `columns` style declarations for exapmle `columns/name/.style={column name=Name,column type={|r|}}`

Answer (score 4):

You can also so this with [the `datatool` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool):

[image]

### Notes:

- I used [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) for `\IfStrEq`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Make csv in question
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists2.csv}
name,surname,
Albert,Einstein,
Marie,Curie,
Thomas,Edison,
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\FormatCell}[1]{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{Curie}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[keys={Name,Surname}]{myDB}{scientists2.csv}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{l l}\toprule
    \textbf{First Name} & \textbf{Last Name}\\\cmidrule{1-2} 
    \DTLforeach*{myDB}{\Name=Name,\Surname=Surname}{%
        \Name & \FormatCell{\Surname} \\
    }%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

**csvsimple version 1.06 released 2012-11-08** does exactly what you want. The code below is your original MWE, the only modification being `\textbf{Curie}` instead of `Curie` within the filecontents environment.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{csvsimple} % requires csvsimple version 1.06 released 2012-11-08

 % Make csv in question
 \begin{filecontents*}{scientists2.csv}
 name,surname
 Albert,Einstein
 Marie,\textbf{Curie}
 Thomas,Edison
 \end{filecontents*}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \csvreader[tabular=|l|l|,
     table head=\hline \textbf{ First Name} & \textbf{Last Nmae} \\\hline,
     late after line = \\\hline]%
 {scientists2.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname}%
 {\name & \surname}%

 \end{center}


 \end{document}
```

It is also worth checking out the new "Macro code inside the data" section in the documentation (p.21). The code below has been taken directly from this section.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{scrreprt}
 \usepackage{tikz,csvsimple,filecontents}
 \begin{document} 

  %-- file embedded for simplicity --
 \begin{filecontents*}{macrodata.csv}
 type,description,content
 M,A nice \textbf{formula},         $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{x} = \ln|x|+c$
 G,A \textcolor{red}{colored} ball, {\tikz \shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (.5cm);}
 M,\textbf{Another} formula,        $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$
 \end{filecontents*}
 %-- end embedded file --

 \csvautotabular{macrodata.csv}


 \csvstyle{my enumerate}{head to column names}


 \begin{enumerate}
 \csvreader[my enumerate]{macrodata.csv}{}{\item \description:\par\content}
 \end{enumerate}


 Now, formulas only:

 \begin{enumerate} 
 \csvreader[my enumerate,filter equal={\type}{M}]{macrodata.csv}{}{%
   \item \description:\qquad\content}
 \end{enumerate}



 \end{document}
```

"Mega cool", as my kids would say :-).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  You can upload images, using the icon of a picture, and then just remove the `!1` and a user with privileges can put that back in for you.

Comment: Also, it appears that this will bold **all** data in the second column? I think the OP wanted to only highlight a single cell, not the entire column.

Comment: I have updated my packages and updated your post with the image as generated by v1.06 of `cvssimple`. Also, I am unable to get your second example to compile: I get `Runaway argument?`.

Comment: Thou art absolutely correct in stating my suggestion boldifies the complete column. If you only want *ONE* cell entry to be bold, you just boldify that one entry within the filecontents environment while dropping \textbf{...} within the csvreader command.

Comment: It turns out that `filecontents` has an issue if there is a leading space before the `\begin`,`\end`.  Added image for you of second example.  But even with the second case you have the formatting as part of the data. Usually I try to separate content from formatting.