# Drawing timeline

Tags: pgfplots, plot, charts

I have a dataset which consists of repeating events over time. Each event takes an arbitrary amount of time. I could plot this using `gnuplot` but am unable to produce correct keys because of the hackish nature of script. I had to manually draw legends. The plot looks like this:
[image: timeline via gnuplot]

Could I do something like this via TikZ or some other graphing tool?

My dataset looks as follows:

```
running 20
stage-out 47
running 34
stage-in 3
running 24
stage-out 39
...
```

As shown above, the file is a two-column text where the first column represents event name and the second column the time interval for that event.

Comment: What kind of data structure do you have? Can you include a small sample of it via `filecontents` package? See this one as an example : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82249/bold-one-cell-in-table-using-csv-reader

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After all my failed attempts [(deleted)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82264/16595) I got one version to work.

The problem was, that inside of the `axis` environment the loop of `\DTLforeach` didn't expand the macros at the proper moment, but after the loop ended. This led to the result that only one (i.e. the last) box was drawn.

This solution circumvents this as it assembles all the TikZ commands before (`\eappto`) but `\draw` or `\fill` must not be expanded which is the reason it is preceded by `\noexpand`.

## Solution 1

This solution uses `pgfplots` only for the axes, the boxes are drawn by `TikZ`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separator={{ }}]{datatool}% loads etoolbox
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\maximum{0}
\def\whattodraw{}

\begin{filecontents}{dataset.dat}
running 20
stage-out 47
running 34
stage-in 3
running 24
stage-out 39
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{datasetcolor.dat}
stage-in red!75
stage-out green
running orange
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={name,value},headers={name,value}]{dataset}{dataset.dat}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={namec,color},headers={namec,color}]{datasetcolor}{datasetcolor.dat}

\DTLforeach*{datasetcolor}{\name=namec,\tikzColor=color}{
        \tikzset{DSCOLOR\name/.estyle={fill=\tikzColor}}
}

\DTLforeach{dataset}{\name=name,\val=value}{
    \DTLappendtorow{cumval}{\maximum}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\maximum}{\maximum+\val}
}

\DTLforeach*{dataset}{\nameb=name,\valb=value,\cumval=cumval}{%
    \eappto\whattodraw{\noexpand\fill [DSCOLOR\nameb] (axis cs:\cumval,0.5) rectangle %
%       node[rotate=90,text width=2cm,align=center] {\nameb} %
        ++ (axis cs:\valb,1);%
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\DTLforeach*{datasetcolor}{\name=namec,\tikzColor=color}{
        \tikz\fill[DSCOLOR\name] (0,0) rectangle (2em,1.3ex); & \name \\
}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=\maximum,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=bottom,
    height=5cm,
    legend columns=-1,
    width=\textwidth,
    xlabel={$t/{\textrm s}\quad (t_{\max} = \maximum)$}
]
\whattodraw
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Solution 2

This solution uses the `xbar stacked` style from `pgfplots`. There are no calculations needed, this is all done by `pgfplots` (thanks to `stack dir=plus` we don't even need to culuminate the entries).

Sadly, the `scatter` classes and the legend have yet to be built manually.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separator={{ }}]{datatool}% loads etoolbox
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\whattodraw{}

\begin{filecontents}{dataset.dat}
running 20
stage-out 47
running 34
stage-in 3
running 24
stage-out 39
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{datasetcolor.dat}
stage-in red!75
stage-out green
running orange
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={name,value},headers={name,value}]{dataset}{dataset.dat}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={name,color},headers={name,color}]{datasetcolor}{datasetcolor.dat}

\DTLforeach{datasetcolor}{\name=name,\tikzColor=color}{
    \tikzset{DSCOLOR\name/.estyle={fill=\tikzColor}}
}

\DTLforeach*{dataset}{\namea=name,\vala=value}{%
    \eappto\whattodraw{%
        \noexpand\addplot[
            scatter,
            DSCOLOR\namea,
            no marks,
            draw=none,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic
        ] coordinates {(\vala,0) [\namea]};
    }
}

\begin{document}
\ref{legendhere}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=bottom,
    xbar stacked,
    stack dir=plus,
    height=5cm,
    legend columns=-1,
    width=\textwidth,
    legend to name={legendhere},
    scatter/classes={
        stage-in={red!75},%
        running={orange},%
        stage-out={green}}
]
\whattodraw
\legend{stage-in,running,stage-out}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Solution without `pgfplots`

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[separator={{ }}]{datatool}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\maximum{0}

\newlength{\barHeight}\newlength{\barWidth}\newlength{\currentX}\newlength{\nextX}
\setlength{\barHeight}{2cm}
\setlength{\barWidth}{10cm}
\setlength{\currentX}{0cm}

\begin{filecontents}{dataset.dat}
running 20
stage-out 47
running 34
stage-in 3
running 24
stage-out 39
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datasetcolor.dat}
stage-in red!75
stage-out green
running orange
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={name,value},headers={name,value}]{dataset}{dataset.dat}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={namec,color},headers={namec,color}]{datasetcolor}{datasetcolor.dat}

\DTLforeach*{datasetcolor}{\name=namec,\tikzColor=color}{
    \tikzset{DSCOLOR\name/.estyle={fill=\tikzColor}}
}
\DTLforeach{dataset}{\name=name,\val=value}{
    \DTLappendtorow{cumval}{\maximum}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\maximum}{\maximum+\val}
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DTLforeach*{dataset}{\name=name,\val=value}{
    \pgfmathsetlength{\nextX}{\val/\maximum*\the\barWidth}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \fill [DSCOLOR\name] (\the\currentX,0) rectangle ++ (\the\nextX,\the\barHeight);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \draw[|-|,shorten >=-.5\pgflinewidth,shorten <=-.5\pgflinewidth] (\the\currentX,.5*\the\barHeight) -- node [below] {\val} ++ (\the\nextX,0) ;
    \pgfmathsetlength{\currentX}{\currentX+\nextX}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks much! I'll go ahead and accept it right away as this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @ketan You're welcome. If you only have three kinds of events, you can easily do the classes' definition manually (and the legend, too). For the magnified part I recommend the `spy` TikZ-library.

Comment: Any chances the second solution code is missing some closing brace somewhere? I'm getting: Runaway argument?
\@nil \let \@dtl@line =\@dtl@trmstr \ifx \@dtl@line \@longempty \else \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@dtl@trim.

Comment: @ketan That seems to be a problem with `datatool`. Maybe your dataset has some irregularities (something about trimming)?

Comment: @ketan Could you resolve those issues? [Apparently blank lines are an issue for `datatool`.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82501/how-to-draw-multiple-rectangles-from-input-data-file?lq=1#comment176928_82505)