# How to draw multiple Rectangles from input data file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I want to draw set of rectangles on axis based on input file. My `.tex` file should be some thing like that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=8cm,
height=8cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-1, xmax=20,
ymin=-1, ymax=20,
xlabel={i},
ylabel={j},
title={Hi}]
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\table;
for each row in table
if (\gg=0)
{
\draw [black, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs:\x,\y) rectangle (axis cs:\xx,\yy);
\end{axis}
else if (\gg=1)
\draw [black, fill=red, thick] (axis cs:\x,\y) rectangle (axis cs:\xx,\yy);
\end{axis}
else if (\gg=2)
\draw [black, fill=red, thick] (axis cs:\x,\y) rectangle (axis cs:\xx,\yy);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where as my input file look like

```
%% data.dat 
x   y   xx  yy  gg  
0   0   5   4   0   
0   4   5   9   1
0   9   5   13  0
0   13  5   16  1
5   0   9   5   2
```

How can I draw them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: What is the difference between `\gg=1` and `\gg=2`?

Comment: Cross-posting is no-go unless you link properly (if you ask me)!

http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21907

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution does use [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) instead of [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) (I can't find a reference to loop over data in a `pgfplotstable`) and is based on [a previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82303/16595) of mine.

I replaced all `TAB` characters with `,` as `TAB` is not very LaTeX-friendly and `,` is the default separator.

The solution uses [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s tools to concatenate all `\draw` commands in one macro `\mydraws`.

There are two macros used:

- `\appto<macro>{<code>}` and
- `\eappto<macro>{<code>}`.

While the first one just appends `<code>` to the macro `<macro>` the latter will expand `<code>` first.
We don't want `\draw` to be expanded because Ti*k*Z should deal with it alone; but we want `\c`, `\x`, `\y`, `\xx` and `\yy` expanded because the hold the actual values. If we wouldn't expand these macros they would first be expanded when we use `\mydraws` inside the `\tikzpicture` but now they all have the value of the last row, and we would only get one box (but drawn five times) …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x,y,xx,yy,gg
0,0,5,4,0
0,4,5,9,1
0,9,5,13,0
0,13,5,16,1
5,0,9,5,2
\end{filecontents}
\DTLloaddb[
    headers={x,y,xx,yy,gg},
    keys={x,y,xx,yy,gg}
]{data}{data.dat}
\begin{document}
\def\mydraws{}% \def is a TeX primitive, one could have said \newcommand*\mydraws{}, too.
\DTLforeach*{data}{\x=x,\y=y,\xx=xx,\yy=yy,\gg=gg}{
%   \PackageWarning{}{x=\x, y=\y, xx=\xx, yy=\yy, gg=\gg} % DEBUG
    \def\c{blue}
    \ifnum\gg=0\relax
        \def\c{blue}
    \else\ifnum\gg=1\relax
        \def\c{red}
    \else
        \def\c{red}
    \fi\fi
    \appto\mydraws{\draw}% \draw will not be expanded
    \eappto\mydraws{ [black, fill=\c, thick] (axis cs:\x,\y) rectangle (axis cs:\xx,\yy);}% \c, \x, \y, \xx and \yy will be expanded to their actual value.
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=8cm,
height=8cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-1, xmax=20,
ymin=-1, ymax=20,
xlabel={i},
ylabel={j},
title={Hi}]
\mydraws
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Ouput

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for answering me.Both solutions look exactly what I want. But when I try to compile them, they give errors that I don't understand (As I am a newbie on Latex)
***@Qrrbrbirlbel Solution*** the error is 
Runaway argument?
\@nil \let \@dtl@line =\@dtl@trmstr \ifx \@dtl@line \@longempty \@dtl@condition
true \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@dtl@trim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> solution_file.tex

***@percusse solution***
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \mycolor 
l.30 ]{drawer}{\mytable}

Thanks

Comment: The OP of the other question ran in the same problem. Do you maybe have a blank line in your `data.dat`? Otherwise try to remove (or comment out) lines from the file and test again.

Answer (score 5):

Also a `pgfplotstable` solution with a custom column cretaed from existing ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x   y   xx  yy  gg  
0   0   5   4   0   
0   4   5   9   1
0   9   5   13  0
0   13  5   16  1
5   0   9   5   2
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\mytable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/assign/.code={%
\getthisrow{x}\pointaa
\getthisrow{y}\pointab
\getthisrow{xx}\pointba
\getthisrow{yy}\pointbb
\getthisrow{gg}\mycolor
\pgfmathparse{\mycolor<2?(\mycolor<1?"blue":"red"):"green"}
\edef\temp{%
\noexpand\draw[black,fill=\pgfmathresult] 
             (axis cs:\pointaa,\pointab) rectangle (axis cs:\pointba,\pointbb);}
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\temp
}
]{drawer}{\mytable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=8cm,
height=8cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-1, xmax=20,
ymin=-1, ymax=20,
xlabel={i},
ylabel={j},
title={Hi},
]
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{drawer}\of\mytable\as\cell{\cell}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering me.Both solutions look exactly what I want. But when I try to compile them, they give errors that I don't understand (As I am a newbie on Latex)
***@Qrrbrbirlbel Solution*** the error is 
Runaway argument?
\@nil \let \@dtl@line =\@dtl@trmstr \ifx \@dtl@line \@longempty \@dtl@condition
true \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@dtl@trim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> solution_file.tex

***@percusse solution***
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \mycolor 
l.30 ]{drawer}{\mytable}

Thanks